# How to create a dataset in c# programmatically?

Tags: c#, dataset, report

I was hoping there is a way to dynamically create a dataset in Visual Studio (I'm using c#)
I know you can just create one the "click and drag" way, but was hoping there is a way to create one dynamically because I need to put data in a report that has been gathered from any database and any table and any column .

(I have a program that can connect to any mysql or sql database, and display any table and any column.)

Now I need to put that in a report.
But first a dataset.

```
DataTable table1 = new DataTable("patients");
table1.Columns.Add("name");
table1.Columns.Add("id");
table1.Rows.Add("sam", 1);
table1.Rows.Add("mark", 2);

DataTable table2 = new DataTable("medications");
table2.Columns.Add("id");
table2.Columns.Add("medication");
table2.Rows.Add(1, "atenolol");
table2.Rows.Add(2, "amoxicillin");

// Create a DataSet and put both tables in it.
DataSet set = new DataSet("office");
set.Tables.Add(table1);
set.Tables.Add(table2);


// TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'SwimkidzDataSet.Branches' table. 
// You can move, or remove it, as needed.
this.BranchesTableAdapter.Fill(this.manuallyCreatedDataset.Branches);
```

Tried this but no chance it will work

```
this.BranchesTableAdapter.Fill(set);
this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

Comment: I guess "dynamically" means in code? The remove the VS2010 tag and add a language.

Comment: i changed it, but, the question is, can visual studio pick up datasets made in memory. Thatsss why i had the vs2010 tag, because in my brain, i see that ill have to create one that adds it to my vs project?

Comment: damn... a whole new plug in to get to know....
Coz i tried this and dont think it would work (added it)

Comment: @Henk Holterman No you dont have to get crystal ball plug in to do this. i found the answer

Comment: yea you are right. Sorry about that though. Guess sometimes you dont know how to ask what you really want.

Answer (score 0):

I have a wrapper-base report process I use.  So, each report in my system is derived from the same underlying report generator / view / pdf output / auto-email, etc.  Within the class, I have a property "RptDS" which is representative of a "DataSet" with multiple tables such as you have created in your scenario.

So, my "rv" variable is the instance of the "ReportViewer" that has the .rdlc report definition loaded.  Now, I just loop through the RptDS (DataSet) of each table and copy into a corresponding REPORT Data source and carry the table name along for the ride.  Set the VALUE equal to whatever the DataTable IS.  Add that to the local report and go.

```
foreach( DataTable dt in RptDS.Tables )
{
    var dsi = new ReportDataSource();
    dsi.Name = dt.TableName;
    dsi.Value = dt;
    rv.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(dsi);
}
```